# How to pass on Jenkins Build Parameters to JMETER Property Variable

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to configure Jenkins Build Parameter "users" ,to be passed as input to `JMETER (v5.1) --> No.Of Threads`  using the function:`${__javaScript(Math.round(${XX}))}`

While executing test i am getting following error

> error :  caused by jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ParserException::1:12 Expected but found { Math.round(${__jexl())}

Comment: Please provide some more details on how you are passing the Jenkins build parameter "users" to JMeter. Also, why use a function like Math.round for No. of threads? Isn't it a whole number to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to store `Math.round(${`. Test it with println. Then Invoke `${__javaScript(myVariable)}`. Nested `${}` is a bad idea, groovy interprets them.

as M Navneet Krishna said, your question is a bit succinct for us to provide better answer. But I gave you a method that should help you debug your stuff